# read csv file inside package

Tags: python, csv

Sorry if this question is stupid, but I'm kind of a python newbie.

I'm trying to port a python 2.7 code base to python 3.4...
I found this code snippet which should iterate over a csv file inside the packed application.
Although PyDev is telling me, that pkg_resources.respource_stream is undefined the first line seems to work, causing the 3rd line to throw this error: `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

```
io = pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, "data.csv")
c = csv.reader(io)
for record in c:
    #doStuff
```

I tried switching the method to resource_string, ResourceManager.resourceStream etc. but all I got was different errors.

Comment: The problem is that you get a file object opened in binary mode not text mode (as documented), so it returns bytes not strings. I leave it to someone else to come up with a good solution or show me a builtin function which does what is needed in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pkg_resources.resource_stream` returns a stream that reads in binary mode; it just returns the bytes read, and doesn't try to decode them using a particular encoding.

Most tools for encoding and decoding text are found in the [`codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html). To convert a binary reader into a text reader given a particular encoding, use [`codecs.getreader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.getreader). Since you are bundling this file yourself, you should know the encoding, which should probably be UTF-8. So you would write:

```
io = pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, "data.csv")
utf8_reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
c = csv.reader(utf8_reader(io))
for record in c:
    # doStuff
```